# Ошибка настройки Nginx для двух сайтов

Tags: nginx, docker

Всем привет.

У меня есть два приложения - одно для авторизации и второе для прокси. Авторизацию хочу слушать на 80 порту, а прокси - на 5001. Хочу их запускать докерами. Сделал докер-компоус и создал такой конфиг для нжинкс:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask_main:5000;

        # Do not change this
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {

    listen 5001 proxy_server;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://flask_proxy:5001;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /;
    }
}
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
nginx    | nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "proxy_server" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/project.conf:17
```

Comment: У вас тут какая-то рекурсия получилась. nginx слушает 5001 и проксирует в 5001. Так обычно не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default_server` - это не название, это указатель на то, что при наличии нескольких `listen 80` с разными `server_name` именно этот блок будет обрабатывать запросы на адреса, не перечисленные ни в одном `server_name`.

[Как nginx обрабатывает запросы](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html)

В вашем случае надо в строке
`listen 5001 proxy_server;`
убрать `proxy_server` или заменить на `default_server`

Comment: Pavel Zaberin, да, Вы правы, разобрался с этим. Спасибо.

Comment: Pavel Zaberin, а еще один вопрос. У меня в докере указано такое:

proxy:
        build: ./proxy
        container_name: flask_proxy
        restart: always
        command: gunicorn app:app -b 0.0.0.0:5001
        environment:
            DEBUG: 'True'
        expose:
            - 5001
        depends_on:
            - nginx
            - flask

А nginx при этом ругается: 

host not found in upstream "flask_proxy" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/project.conf:20

Comment: Судя по синтаксису - docker compose собирает?

Comment: Да, в нем все собирается

Comment: Тогда попробуйте в конфиге nginx указать не `container_name`, как у вас, судя по ошибке, а имя сервиса, в вашем случае это `proxy`. Должно помочь

Comment: Не помогло. Теперь пишет nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "proxy" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/project.conf:20

Comment: Тяжко конечно так конфиги читать. У вас `depends_on` в `proxy` и ссылается на `nginx`, верно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127322/discussion-between-pavel-zabelin-and-viktor-andriichuk).

Answer (score 0):

Так как для Nginx необходимо понимать с какого урла какие правила разруливать, тогда нужно прописать в hosts соответствующие домены и тогда Nginx поймет, что куда ему отправлять.